# Calculating resistance for 50% duty cycle

Tags: timing-analysis, multivibrator

I am planning for simple standalone LED flashers to fill the ceiling of a room. Planning to fix at least 60 of these and they will be flashing randomly at about once a second.

[image]

I'm using this circuit. Rb of 100K and Cb of 10microfarads are chosen to give the required timing. By experimenting with various values, I can decide what to use for Rc to achieve the 50% duty cycle. Rc must be matched to the current in the LED to achieve the 50% duty cycle?

What I want to ask is, is there any other more straightforward method to estimated the Rc?

I haven't order the LEDs yet, so I need advice on that too. It will be the standard size of 5mm plastic cased LEDs.

Comment: at that scale I'd look at addressible LEDs  WS2811 or whatever, or possibly self-blinking LEDS

Comment: that quwstion's a trickly one. the multivibrator switches when the transistor comes out of saturation, so the choice of resistor depends no-only on the current through the capacitor, but also the transistor's gain, how closely it matches it's neighbour, the exacct supply voltage, nearby magnetic fields, *phase of the moon, facial expression, etc.*

Comment: I have more than 250 2sc945...!! This is the reason for that.  Ha ha ha... Jasen, I like your comments... But I feel the unpredictability of the imperfections of analogue is what will make it random. I just want to ensure the on time to off time ratio is as close as possible to one.

Comment: The 12V supply will overdo things on VEB on the transistors .Reduce the supply volts or protect the transistors in some way .

Comment: @Autistic - You should explain why the 12V supply will be a problem with the transistors. It may not be clear to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The 'ideal' solution is to make the circuit completely symmetrical, by using a 360ohm and a LED in the right hand side. Instead of a LED, a string of several silicon diodes could be used to approximate the voltage drop.

Using a larger resistor than 360 in that position would give 50% duty cycle, perhaps in the ratio of vsup to (vsup-vLED), so maybe around 470ohms. Try it and see. Voltage and temperature variations will not be compensated, and will cause a drift away from 50%. The two LED solution stays symmetrical regardless of supply voltage and temperature.

Using two LEDs per circuit is not as profligate as it sounds, as with 60 LEDs on the ceiling flashing nominally randomly, I doubt you could spot without meticulous study if any pair of LEDs was flashing as an on/off pair, especially if they were some way apart. It would therefore save you half of your transistors. Mounting each led on (say) a foot of wire would allow you to get them two feet apart.

On reflection, I agree with autistic's comment that 12v supply is too high. When a TR turns on, its collector takes the base of the opposite transistor down through the 10uF to -(nearly)12v, which exceeds the reverse base-emitter breakdown voltage of most transistors, which is almost always in the 5 or 6v region. Some transistor types will go bang at once, some will survive, and Sod's Law says most will gradually degrade to fail after you have glued all the modules to your ceiling. The easiest way is to reduce the supply to 6v or less, though you can play games with diodes and/or resistors to limit the reverse base voltage or breakdown current that flows, complicating an already fairly complicated circuit.

Does each have its own battery, or is there a supply wire going to each, in which case there are wires all over the place anyway?

It's a pity when one has a large stock of an enticing but inefficient to use component, like those transistors. A much better way to do this would be to use a 74HC14 hex schmidt package as the centre of 6 flashing LEDs from its 6 independent relaxation oscillators. I've made that mistake so many times that I'm starting to notice it in my old age!

Comment: Neil, thank you for the detailed reply. The 7414 flasher is seems to be a good option. Thinking of going for it because I need to build only 10 of them for 6 LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use 360 same as the other side but reduce the voltage at the top end  if a stiff voltage source is used you can trim the duty cycle of all the multivibrators with a single input.

Comment: Reduce the voltage at the top end if a stiff voltage source is used? And/Or, if a stiff voltage source is used you can trim the duty cycle? Trim how?